# Bootstrap's Outline Buttons Behave like Regular Buttons

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Bootstrap's btn-outline-primary class to make a nice looking button like this

[image]

However, when I try and do that in my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

The buttons come out solid

[image]

and I don't know why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: btn-primary-outline is bootstrap 4, which may be why its not working. http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#button-tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`btn-outline-primary` is only available in [Bootstrap v4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/) and you have 3.3.7 loaded. Try giving v4 a whirl to see if it works.

See this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/2LfPCh6dt8) and switch between 3.3.7 and alpha v4 to demo.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the right bootstrap version? `btn-outline-primary` is available only in Bootstrap v4. If you are using older versions, it will not work.